# How can I determine if I'm inside Jersey request scope?

Tags: java, scope, jersey, dropwizard, hk2

I have some code that will run both inside Jersey request context and outside of Jersey request context (in another thread). I have a piece of data I want to access in both cases that's optional, but I need to know if I can pull it from.

Within Jersey request context it comes from a header parameter. I'm using a `org.glassfish.hk2.api.ServiceLocator` to access the `javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestContext` from which I can read the header. However, this is optional, so it may or may not be present. Outside of Jersey request context I'm currently using [MDC](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/mdc.html) to store and read the value, but again, it's optional. (To pass the value between the two, I'm using in [temporal](http://temporal.io) context.) All of this stuff is working.

I want to know where to pull the value from, request context or MDC.

I know that if I try to access `ContainerRequestContext` outside of Jersey's `org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope` and it's `null` I'm not in request scope and should use MDC. But, I get unsilenceable warnings. [An `IllegalStateException` is thrown](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jersey/blob/bdb0dd05560d7611b1650ef35fab468323da8a56/core-common/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/process/internal/RequestScope.java#L153) and logged as a warning inside the service locator (which I can't silence).

One option would be to store a non-optional sentinel value in MDC, since that's always available. When I use temporal to store the optional value, I can set a sentinel. If the sentinel is present, use MDC, if not, use request context.

I think a cleaner way that I'd expect to work is just to check if I'm inside jersey's request scope. However, I can't find a way to do this, either using `RequestScope` or `ServiceLocator`. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You could register an `ApplicationEventListener` that calls your code, e.g.,

```java
public class MyAppEventListener implements ApplicationEventListener {
    @Override
    public RequestEventListener onRequest(final RequestEvent event) {
        return new MyRequestListener();
    }

    public static class MyRequestListener implements RequestEventListener {
        @Override
        public void onEvent(final RequestEvent event) {
            if (event.getType() == RESOURCE_METHOD_START) {
                MyOtherCode.youAreNowInRequestScope();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your service's `run()` method (I see you've tagged this for Dropwizard):

```java
environment.jersey().register(MyAppEventListener.class)
```

Presumably you'll need to tweak this to call something non-static or maybe trigger off a different request event, but I hope it's helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem, the closest thing I have found to do is:

```java
class MyFactory implements Suplier<SomeInterface> {

    @Override
    public SomeInterface get() {
        if (inRequestScope()) {
            return new ClassA();
        } else {
            return new ClassB();
        }
    }

    private boolean inRequestScope() {
        try {
            requestScope.current();
            return true;
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Looking at the [implementation](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jersey/blob/2.x/core-common/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/process/internal/RequestScope.java#L149) of [current](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/apidocs/2.35/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/process/internal/RequestScope.html#current--) this should have no side effects. It's not ideal, but the best solution I could find.

You can also `@Inject` MyFactory with proxies to 2 different implementations, A and B, and return those, or add caching, etc.